PDE with a bell-shaped source
I am trying to find an explicit solution for the following PDE, which can be easily solved numerically:
$$\frac{\partial^2 T(x,t)}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial T(x,t)}{\partial t}$$
with initial condition
$$T(x,0)=0$$
and boundary conditions
$$T(\infty,t)=0$$
$$-\frac{\partial T(0,t)}{\partial x}=\exp \left[ -(t-t_0)^2 \right]$$
with $t_0>3$. I tried with the Laplace transform that using the initial condition and the first boundary conditon gives:
$$\overline{T}(x,s)=c_1 \exp{(-\sqrt{s} \, x)}$$
with $s$ the transform variable.
The constant can be found from the second boundary condition, so that, if no errors were made, the final solution is:
$$\overline{T}(x,s)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}} e^{\frac{1}{4} s (s-4 t_0)} \text{erfc} \left[ \frac{1}{2} (s-2 t_0) \right] \exp{(-\sqrt{s} \, x)}$$
Unfortunately, I am not able to perform the inverse transform. Any help, also using a different approach. Thanks in advance.

$$\overline{T}(x,s)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}} e^{\frac{1}{4} s (s-4 t_0)} \text{erfc} \left[ \frac{1}{2} (s-2 t_0) \right] e^{-\sqrt{s} \, x}$$
Expression $\overline{T}(x,s)$ is not invertible in this form, hence we split it into factors.
$$f(t)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[e^{\frac{1}{4}s(s-4t_0)}\cdot\text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{2}(s-2t_0)\right)\right](t)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-(t-t_0)^2}$$
$$g(x,t)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\cdot \frac{e^{-\sqrt{s} x}}{\sqrt{s}}\right](t)=\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 t}}}{2 \sqrt{t}}$$
We use the convolution theorem
$$T(x,t)=\int_0^t{f(\tau)\cdot g(x,t-\tau)}\; d\tau$$
Can't evaluate the convolution integral in closed form, so we evaluate $T(x,t)$ numerically with Matlab.
Maybe someone here can crack this integral.
Surface plot of $T(x,t)$ with $t_0=3$:

Addendum
Using time-shifting
$$\mathcal{L}_t[g(t-t_0)](s)=e^{-s t_0} \left(\mathcal{L}_t[g(t)](s)\right)+e^{-s t_0} \int_{-t_0}^0 g(t) e^{-s t} \, dt$$
with $g(t)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cdot e^{-t^2}$ and $G(s)=\text{erfc}\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\cdot e^{\frac{s^2}{4}}$
$$\mathcal{L}_t[\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cdot e^{-(t-t_0)^2}](s)= \text{erfc}\left(\frac{s}{2}\right) e^{\frac{s^2}{4}- s t_0} + e^{-s t_0}\cdot \int_{-t_0}^0 \frac{2 e^ {-t^2} e^ {-s t}}{\sqrt{\pi }} \, dt= e^{\frac{s^2}{4}-s t_0} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{s}{2}-t_0\right)\right)+\text{erfc}\left(\frac{s}{2}\right) e^{\frac{s^2}{4}-s t_0}= e^{\frac{1}{4} s (s-4 t_0)}\cdot \text{erfc}\left(\frac{s}{2}-t_0\right)$$

Thanks @gpmath. Could you please add some details about the derivation of $f(t)$? I'd like to learn you method. Thank you.

I was able to simplify $f(t)$.
Use this correspondence and time shifting property of Laplace transform
$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left\text{erfc}\left(\frac{s}{2}\right) e^{\frac{s^2}{4}}\right=\frac{2 e^{-t^2}}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$

Thank you @gpmath. I surrender however, after many atemps, the best I can get is $$e^ {-s t_0} e^{\frac{s^2}{4}} \cdot \text{erfc} \left( \frac{s}{2}-t_0 \right)$$ or $$ e^{t_0} e^ {-s t_0} e^{\left( \frac{s^2}{4}-t_0 \right)} \cdot \text{erfc} \left( \frac{s}{2}-t_0 \right)$$But I am shameful to say that I am not capable of developing further these expressions, also applying the time shifting property. Can you please help me.

Thanks @gpmath. Excuse me, but I have always seen the time shifting formula writen as $\mathcal{L}_tg(t-t_0)=e^{-s t_0} \left(\mathcal{L}tg(t)\right)$, where does the other term, $e^{-s t_0} \int{-t_0}^0 g(t) e^{-s t} , dt$, come from?

$$\mathcal{L}_tg(t-t_0)\cdot \color{red}{u(t-t_0)}=e^{-s t_0} \left(\mathcal{L}_tg(t)\right)$$
$u(t)$ is the Heaviside step function.

Got it finally, thanks @gpmath!
